# Hawking Black Hole Metric

Tags: black-holes, metric-tensor, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

What is the metric for a black hole which is emitting Hawking radiation? Does it depend on previous history or does it depend only on the current mass of the black hole? Are there multiple known coordinate charts useful for working with such a metric?

Comment: [Vaidya metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaidya_metric) I guess. It's often used in analysis of evaporating back holes.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/371129

Comment: @Dale : The question seems to assume that there is only one possiblity.